# Illusion of choice and free will

Tags: free-will

I'm making a presentation and I need to find philosophers who have talked about topics such as free will or the illusion of choice. If you could recommend any, it would be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: This might be rather broad. One place to look might be https://www.iep.utm.edu/freewill/ but there are other places as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know how to mark answer as solved or something, might not have that option because im not logged in

Comment: If you get an answer there will be a check box which you can click to accept it if you find it useful. Best wishes.

Comment: I like Robert Kane's book, [A Contemporary Introduction to Free Will](https://global.oup.com/ushe/product/a-contemporary-introduction-to-free-will-9780195149708?cc=ca&lang=en&).

Comment: How is this on topic?

Comment: I second @adamsharpe's recommendation of Kane's book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my personal opinion, the first place to start is Daniel Dennett's *Elbow Room* which does a fairly accessible explanation of compatiblism.  Sam Harris' *Free Will* is current and easy to follow, but not a deep treatment.   I would then go to John Searle who wrote a bit on the topic and is collected in *Freedom and Neurobiology: Reflections on Free Will, Language, and Political Power*

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Mr. Boss- Let me proceed directly to Spinoza's "Ethics" Part Two- On the Nature and Origin of the Mind; 
Proposition XLVIII-"In the mind there is no absolute or free will; but the mind is determined to wish this or that by a cause, which has also been determined by another cause, and this last by another cause and so on to infinity."
Transliteration- It must be emphasized that Spinoza in no way is speaking of determined existence but rather of a quite complicated form of necessity.
When anyone makes a choice to act in a certain manner and thinks to themselves that they are exercising a free and unconstrained will, what is actually in play is that the necessity of the particular and unique circumstances of their own nature; their life's environment along with choices that they have made previously, taken together, all exert an influence on the choice which delimits its apparent 'freedom' to such an extent that there is no free-will at play whatsoever.

What is important here is for you to read this proposition, the following proposition, XLVIX, along with each and every of the proofs and notes accompanying both. This would be a total of eight pages. pp.119-128 Hope this proves useful! Charles M. Saunders